# How is it possible that function is fundamentally object type?

Tags: javascript

I'm learning JavaScript. Most of the materials says JavaScript only has 3 primitive types: Number, Boolean, String and 2 special primitive value: null, undefined. And everything else is Object type including array, function, reg expression.

I can easily imagine that array is some kind of special object, but why function also object type? There's nothing similar between object and function. How to implement a special object to work like a function? I have no idea.

Comment: Take a look at the section 'Functions as First-Class Citizens' in this [post](http://skilldrick.co.uk/2010/09/why-javascript-is-awesome/).  It is short and to the point.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to implement an object to work like a function, but you can use a function as an object.

```
 var a = function(){}
 a.x = 5;
 console.log(a.x);
```

The reason everything is an object like that is just a design choice that, for some, is considered elegant. I particularly don't agree, but people don't agree with things, in general.

Also, I should note that a point that is probably being made is that JS functions are first-class. This means you can use a function like you could use any other value, which includes sending them as arguments to other functions and returning functions from functions and so on. Examples below:

```
// return functions from function
function create_a_function_that_doubles_numbers(){
    return function(a){ return a*2; }
}
var double_number = create_a_function_that_doubles_numbers();
console.log(double_number(5)); // 10

// sending a function to a function
function call_twice(f){ 
    f(); f();
};
function shout(){
    alert("HEY");
};
call(shout); 
// Here we send "shout" to "call_twice" which... calls it twice, 
// so a "HEY" popup appears two times.
```

Comment: Actually, functions *are* frequently used as objects. For example, Angular has `$http` that you can call as a low-level function, or you can call `$http.get()` or `$http.post()` as a shorthand and for more expressive code.

Comment: hmmm, I think that using functions as objects can sometimes be useful in order to restrict variables scope from being global...such as when writing jQuery plugins, or javascript in a closure/module pattern

Comment: Functions as objects is very common indeed, the advice is misleading. You encounter higher-order functions in JavaScript very often, and it is not poor practice. I think you're referring to using functions as objects, ie. a map or associative array... But this is not the definition of "Object" in the sense of "everything is an object"

Comment: Point taken, removed the referred part. Please feel free and encouraged to edit the answer as to make it richer. Just a note, high order functions have nothing to do with them being objects, if that is what you mean.